# How do you replace all of the digits with 0 AFTER the first digit?

Tags: design-patterns, lua, integer, digits, roblox

**CLOSED**

I'm trying to convert numbers into a familiar format, for example, **1000** would turn into **1k** and so on. I want it to go up to the **qn** region which I already tried accomplishing and the problem I faced was when I tried rounding the numbers into the nearest first digit.

For example, **59127327** could turn into **60000000** and I would be able to **tostring** and **gsub** that value into **60M**

So what I'm practically looking for is a algorithm to change all the numbers **AFTER** the first digit into 0 whilst maintaining the number of digits the integer has.

Examples:
**100000** -> **100k**

I'm developing a roblox game with a money that has to transform into the the familiar format I stated above. Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need a string-based solution? For the first part something like `math.pow(10,math.floor(math.log10(number)))` would work, and the logarithm could also be used to solve the second one. Question, how should 1582 be represented for the second part of the question? 1K or 1582 or 1.582K ?

Comment: I dont need a string-based solution, I was supposed to say that I'm fine with string solutions. Thank you so much, I'll try out the solution, and it has to be like **1953** to 1.9k

Comment: Should it work the way you want, it would be interesting for posterity to post the chosen solution yourself, **and accept the answer** if not better answer comes in for let's say two days - that's the way SO works. I'd rather not post it myself as I don't know enough Lua to produce an idiomatic solution.

Comment: I understand, thank you anyways as your solution gave me an expansion of ideas to build onto. Hopefully I can solve this myself but any other contributors can hopefully help me with this too.

Comment: Btw the last edit you did has implications: `math.floor` should become `math.round`. But oldskool working in logarithms is the way to go :) Good luck!

Comment: `math.log10 ()` exists only in Lua 5.1. Use `math.log (x)/math.log (10)` instead

Answer (score 1):

So if understanding correctly, you want just one significant digit, possibly followed by up to two zeros so you have 1-3 digits and an order of magnitude that you will convert into a character to display at the end.

First like in @fvu's comment you can use `math.log10` to get the number of digits in the number as the integer portion and the fraction will be how far between 0 and 10 you are.  You can use 'math.modf` to separate those parts.  In lua:

```
local int, frac = math.modf(math.log10(value))
-- 7, 0.77178824606507 for 59127327
```

The order of magnitude is how many thousands you have, so divide the int part by 3.  The mod of that will be the extra zeroes.  The example with 7 digits has a magnitude of 2 (1,000,000) and 1 extra zero (7-2*3):

```
local magnitude = math.floor(int / 3)
local zeroes = int - magnitude * 3
```

Now raising 10 to the power of the fractional part will get you your digit.  Add 0.5 before flooring it if you want to round instead of truncate (sample should be 60m, right?), and add back in the extra zeroes:

```
local digit = math.floor(math.pow(10, frac) + 0.5)
local num = digit * math.pow(10, zeroes)
```

If you wanted to have all displayed digits be significant (i.e. '59m' instead of '60m'), you would add `zeroes` to `frac` before taking 10 to its power:

```
local num = math.floor(math.pow(10, frac + zeroes) + 0.5)
```

Next use the magnitude to get a string (with default for exponential notation if not specified):

```
local powers = {[0]='', 'k', 'm', 'b', 't'}
local magnitudeString = powers[magnitude]
magnitudeString = magnitudeString or 'e'..tostring(magnitude)
```

And combine `num` with `magnitudeString` to get the result:

```
local result = tostring(num)..magnitudeString
```

[codepad link](http://codepad.org/arU4Y3gn), [Here's a link](http://codepad.org/NWQXgire)
to a codepad with a function that takes options for what kind of conversion you want and whether to round or not.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to 100% make it compatible with my scripts but because I found a solid solution, I just had to make a character in between the numbers such as **,** between every 3 digits and I was able to pull it off.

So technically, I don't need any more answers thanks!